# Reading an ERF (Wireshark) file

Tags: c#, wireshark, packet

I am trying to read an `ERF` file and read all its `Packets` using [this](https://wiki.wireshark.org/ERF) format schema.

This is my file:

[image]

I marked where the packet start (this file contains only 1 packet) and the `Length`.

I've been trying to understand the format with no success, so my question is: how do I find the packet `Timestamp`?

Comment: This is TCP Packet, i know where the packet start and end (marked), but the time stamp should be before this start point and i want to know how to read it

Comment: I believe timestamps are optional for TCP. So you'd need to look in the option area of the tcp header.

Comment: You should post your attempt to do this so we have a starting point to help you.

Comment: I don't know where to start that's why i have nothing, i didn't understand this format schema ,this is all i have.

Answer (score 1):

According to the format specification, the timestamp is in first 8 bytes, little-endian ordered.

So in your example, the timestamp has a low-part of first four bytes: `0x92`, `0x8F`, `0xDD`, `0xB1`, giving you `0xB1DD8F92`, and a high-part of `0x4E`, `0x74`, `0xF5`, `0x4F` giving you `0x4FF5744E`.

According to the spec, you can now just take the high-part and put into your favourite unix time converter as decimal (`1341486158`) and you'll get the timestamp with seconds precision.